# TYPO3 9: Recursive count subpages of root page

Tags: typo3-9.x

is TYPO3 able to collect recursive and show the amount of subpages (no storages) from a specific root page? Tried this typoscript snippet but it is not working somehow.

```
20 = CONTENT
20 {
   table = pages
   select {
      selectFields = count(*)
      pidInList = <ROOT-PID>
      andWhere = (hidden=0 AND deleted=0)
   }
   renderObj = COA
   renderObj {
      10 = TEXT
      10 {
         field = count(*)
         wrap = Counted pages: |
      }
   }
}
```

Maybe there is some function in TYPO3 9?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the data is stored as a tree you need a recursion to get all pages from all sublevels.

As you can't know the depth (or expect a high number) and typoscript as a configuration language has no recursion build in a pure typoscript solution would be complicated.

Here a userfunc written in PHP and with recursion could be a quick solution.

---

In general:
Why do you need that number?
Maybe there is a simpler solution

---

here a pure typoscript solution you might start with:

for each menu-entry you get the sum of all pages up to three levels deeper and the count of pages on the next level.

```
temp.menudef = TMENU
temp.menudef {
    #target = _top
    noBlur = 1
    #expAll = 1
    wrap = <ol>|</ol>
    NO = 1
    NO {
        stdWrap.cObject = COA
        stdWrap.cObject {
            1 = TEXT
            1.field = title
            1.required = 1

            10 = LOAD_REGISTER
            10.level1uids.cObject = COA
            10.level1uids.cObject {
                10 = CONTENT
                10.table = pages
                10.select.pidInList.data = field:uid
                10.renderObj = TEXT
                10.renderObj.field = uid
                10.renderObj.wrap = |,
                20 = TEXT
                #20.field = uid
                20.data = field:uid
            }
            10.level2uids.cObject < .10.level1uids.cObject
            10.level2uids.cObject.10.select.pidInList.data = register:level1uids
            10.level2uids.cObject.20.data = register:level1uids

            10.level3uids.cObject < .10.level1uids.cObject
            10.level3uids.cObject.10.select.pidInList.data = register:level2uids
            10.level3uids.cObject.20.data = register:level2uids

            20 = TEXT
            20.wrap = <!-- --> (|
            20.required = 1
            20.override.numRows.table = pages
            20.override.numRows.select.pidInList.data = register:level3uids
            20.override.stdWrap.ifEmpty =
            20.override.stdWrap.ifEmpty.wrap = |

            30 = TEXT
            30.wrap = -|)
            30.required = 1
            30.override.numRows.table = pages
            30.override.numRows.select.pidInList.field = uid
            30.override.stdWrap.ifEmpty =
            30.override.stdWrap.ifEmpty.wrap = |
        }

    }
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    NO.accessKey = 1

    ACT < .NO
    #ACT = 1
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="activ">|</li>

    SPC < .NO
    #SPC = 1
    SPC.wrapItemAndSub = <li><span class="spacer">|</span></li>

    CUR < .ACT
    #CUR = 1
    CUR.linkWrap = <span class="act">|</span>
    CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current">|</li>
}


temp.submenu = HMENU
temp.submenu {
    entryLevel = 0
    wrap = <div  class="smenu">|</div>

    1 < temp.menudef
    2 < .1
    3 < .2
    4 < .3
    5 < .4
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I want to get the amount of pages for each root page in a multi-site TYPO3 for statistic purposes. Before I start to develop this by my own I think there might be a TYPO3 solution in the backend.

Comment: I digged in my old installation and found a solution in pure typoscript.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solution and report back here.